# How to deal with Tslint error exceeds 100 characters when using imports in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am importing a file:

```
import { BodyTableHeaderExampleModule } from '../../components/example-table/example-table-header/example-table-header-xxxx/example-table-header-xxxxx.module';
```

However, tslint is complaining that the line exceeds 100 characters. When I try to minimize line length, by doing the following:

```
import { BodyTableHeaderExampleModule } from '../../components/example-table/example-table-header/' +
'example-table-header-xxxx/example-table-header-xxxxx.module';
```

I receive the following tslint errors:

```
ERROR: 11:92  semicolon             Missing semicolon
ERROR: 11:93  no-unused-expression  unused expression, expected an assignment or function call
```

Any suggestions on a way to remedy the `Exceeds maximum line length of 100` when using long Typescript file imports, would be more than appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few options here

1. You could rather rewrite the import into

   ```
   import { 
     BodyTableHeaderExampleModule 
   } from '../../components/example-table/example-table-header/example-table-header-xxxx/example-table-header-xxxxx.module';
   ```

   But yes, this would still be over a 100 characters
2. You could simply disable that tslint rule for that one line
3. We actually disabled that rule all together and instead started using [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) to reformat our code. Now some lines might be too long, but most of them are formatted correctly and the hassle you described is gone
4. Importing such a deep module in node (you seem to be using Angular, but you're still using node style of importing modules) is actually bad practice. And you might want to re-export that `BodyTableHeaderExampleModule` somewhere within that path.

Except 1. which won't still work for you, the other 3 solutions are all valid. For a long term solution, I'd myself probably solve it as described in 4. - and re-export the module somewhere in `../../components/example-table/example-table-header` or similar. But choose what's best for your project and your need.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option to ignore patterns from the max-line-rule.

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/max-line-length/

Example:

```
"max-line-length": [
  true,
  {
    "limit": 120,
    "ignore-pattern": "^import "
  }
],
```